# Passing Sessions via link not working

Tags: email, custom-form, session, session-storage

I have a customized form where it uses sessions to pre-populate some of the fields based on the previous item from a list.

The sessions looks like the following:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("systemStuff" + index, stuffItem[index].System);
```

Works great.

However when we send the link to the customized form via email, the pre-populated fields are blank.

Is this because it's an empty session value?

Sorry, still trying to figure out SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sessionStorage object is stored in web browser.it gets deleted when browser tab is closed.
It stores values only for single session. If you want to pre-popluated fields for user who open links in email, Local storage will not work, user can open email in any machine.

Best way to do this is pass via query string and read query string and  pre-popluate.

Comment: Thank you.  Does sessionStorage have a time limit also? Because the person was working on it, left for a meeting, then the prepopulation was cleared.  Just trying to document and explain to customers how a session can be cleared.  I'll tell them that it's a web browser session and if you copy and paste the link and send to another person via email, the pre-populated information's session will not carry over to the indented audience's session.